# delayed_job -i via cron script through ruby will not start after stopping previous processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

So I have a weird situation, I have delayed_job 2.0.7 and daemons 1.0.10 and ruby 1.87 & rails 2.3.5 running on Scientific Linux release 6.3 (Carbon).

I have a rake task that restarts delayed jobs each night and then does a bunch of batch processing. I used to just do ruby script/delayed_job stop and then start. I have added a backport of named queues that has allowed me to do named queues. So because of this I want to start several processes of each type of named queue. To do this, it seems the best way I found is to use -i to name each process differently so they don't collide.

I wrote some ruby code to do this looping and it works great in dev, it works great on the command line, it works great when called from the rails console. But when called from cron it fails silently, the call returns false but no error message.

```
# this works
system_call_result1 = %x{ruby script/delayed_job stop}
SnapUtils.log_to_both "result of stop all - #{system_call_result1} ***"

# this works
system_call_result2 = %x{mv log/delayed_job.log log/delayed_job.log.#{Date.today.to_s}}
SnapUtils.log_to_both "dj log file has been rotated"

# this fails, result is empty string, if I use system I get false returned
for x in 1..DELAYED_JOB_MAX_THREAD_COUNT
  system_call_result = %x{ruby script/delayed_job -i default-#{x} start}
  SnapUtils.log_to_both "result of start default queue iteration #{x} - #{system_call_result} ***"
end

# this fails the same way
for y in 1..FOLLOWERS_DELAYED_JOB_MAX_THREAD_COUNT
  system_call_result = %x{ruby script/delayed_job --queue=follower_ids -i follower_ids-#{y} start}
  SnapUtils.log_to_both "result of start followers queue iteration #{y} - #{system_call_result} ***"
end
```

So I did lots of trial and found that this problem only happens if I used -i - named processes and only happens if I stop them, then try to start them. If I remove the stops then everything works fine.

Again this is only when I use cron.

If I use command line or console to run, it works fine.

So my question is, what could cron be doing differently that causes these named dj processes not to start if you previously stopped them in the same ruby process?

thanks
Joel

Comment: Have you checked the cron log? It's `/var/log/syslog` usually.  Also note that when a user's cron job runs it is not a normal login session, so certain required environment variables may not be set.

Comment: Yes, checked it, no obvious issues. Thanks

Comment: Cron likely has different environment variables set up. You may need to explicitly set RAILS_ENV. I've had similar issues with cron in the past that I've been able to fix by calling rake tasks instead of script/... (not sure why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured this out, when checking to see if cron would send email, we found that sendmail was broken, the version of mysql that sendmail wanted was not installed, so we fixed that and then our problem magically went away. I would still offer the bounty to anyone that can explain exactly why..